# Laravel 4 Destroy one record from many to many relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I've done this a lot of times but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work this time. I have users and they have permissions. I have a permissions table, users table, and a users_permissions table. The users_permissions table has a series of ids from the users table and series of permissions ids from the permissions table. .For example:
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 3
and so on... Basically, I do a

```
$up = UserPermissions::where('user_id','=',$userid)->where('permission_id','=',$permissionid)->first();
$up->delete();
```

This gets it but I can just do a $up->delete() because the records don't have an id. Is there a way to do this without modifying my tables? Thanks!

```
Nick
```

Comment: I figured it out.  You just do a UserPermissions::where('user_id','=',$uid)->where('permissions_id','=',$pid)->delete();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationships are properly defined:

In `User.php`

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('UserPermission');
    }
}
```

In `UserPermission.php`

```
class UserPermission extends Eloquent
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

To remove permission with id $permissionid from user with id $userid you just need

```
User::find($userid)->permissions()->detach($permissionid);
```

To remove all permissions from user with id $userid

```
User::find($userid)->permissions()->detach();
```